# What does the term "Feature" mean in OpenNLP? Or in NLP in general. Layman term would be nice

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I was working on OpenNLP project and encounter some stuff such as Feature Generation. What exactly does the term "feature" meant? It would be great if you could explain it in laymans term

Comment: Florian is right, but for NLP feature-processing often is a bit more complex. You can start [here](https://cleartk.github.io/cleartk/docs/tutorial/feature_extraction.html), although i only skimmed through it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use OpenNLP but a feature in machine learning terms is an Input for a Classifier/Regressor/other Model.

If you want to classify wether a human is male or female your features could be:

1. Size
2. List item
3. Weight
4. Hair Length

Based on these four features you could make a classification wether its a man or a woman.

On more Complex Data feature generation could mean you summarize a lot of data in some features.
E.g. Standard Deviation of 100 Values. Or Maximum or....

Answer (score 0):

The other answers give a general idea of what a feature is.  For OpenNLP and most other Maximum entropy classifiers, a feature is really an indicator function of whether or not a term appears with a class, I(C,x) where c is the outcome class, x is the term and I=0 if the term appears with the class (see [presentation by Chris Manning](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs224n/cs224n.1162/handouts/MaxentTutorial-16x9-FeatureClassifiers.pdf) for a better description).  ]

In openNLP (and other maxent packages), it is easy to confuse the term (actually, we should call it predicate not term, which is typically a word) with the feature (a function).  However, if you look at [the simple football example that comes with OpenNLP](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/opennlp/tags/opennlp-1.5.2-incubating-rc2/opennlp-maxent/samples/sports/README) (in the US, we would call it soccer), you will see it doesn't need to be a unigram; it could be something like home=arsenal.  You could have  [w-1:last,w:night] represent the bigram last night.

A few other terms you may want to know.  An event is one data point with all your predicates for that data point (and the outcome if training).  The context is the set of predicates used to train/evaluate an outcome. So, Predicates are the "terms" that you are looking for.

Here is an example from the [openNLP football data set](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/opennlp/tags/opennlp-1.5.2-incubating-rc2/opennlp-maxent/samples/sports/football.dat).

```
home=man_united Beckham=false Scholes=true Neville=true Henry=true Kanu=true Parlour=false Ferguson=confident Wengler=tense arsenal_lost_previous man_united_won_previous arsenal
home=arsenal Beckham=false Scholes=true Neville=true Henry=true Kanu=true Parlour=false Ferguson=confident Wengler=tense arsenal_lost_previous man_united_won_previous arsenal
```

each of the terms (e.g. home=man_united) is a predicate (most people use the term feature, but the feature is home=man_united and the outcome -- arsenal).
each line is an event.

I hope it helps..